Suppress engagers from the journey builder eBlast and send the same eBlast to non-openers using journey builder
I sent an eBlast using journey builder to my subscribers. Based on their engagement activity, a new record was created and updated in the CRM subsequently, the DE was updated with a boolean value.
I have to now send the same eblast to the non-openers of this eBlast. I see that journey builder doesn't let us suppress any data. I tried the filter contacts option, it asks me to drag the attributes however, the option to drag these attributes is not visible.
Is there a way I can do this without manually removing the engaged contacts?

You can create a filtered DE to filter out people who were updated with the boolean value in the DE, then use this filtered DE for the new send.
Or you can create exclusion script for the email activity in your new journey builder.

Thanks! I used the filtered DE option
